# Possible to extract part of $BRANCH_NAME string in Jenkins Pipeline?

Tags: git, jenkins, tags, jenkins-pipeline, multibranch-pipeline

I am currently building a multibranch pipeline. I am trying to build a docker image and tagging it with the branch name which will always be "feature/XXX-111". However, when i get the branch name using the $branch_name env variable the docker build with tag -t command doesnt like the "/" in the "feature/XXX-111" branch name. So i was wondering if it was possible to only get the "XXX-111" part of the branch name and dropping the "feature/". Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This works:

```
def branch_name = 'feature/XXX-111'
def regex_to_search = 'feature/([\\w-_]*)'
def matcher = branch_name =~ regex_to_search
if (matcher.find()) {  
    println matcher.group(1)
}
```

Output:

```
XXX-111
```

Comment: thank you but the branch name will be changing constantly, so that is why i am using the $GIT_BRANCH variable to pull in the branch name. So i dont think i can set branch_name = $GIT_BRANCH ?right?

Comment: Start with `def branch_name = GIT_BRANCH` and move from there.

Answer (score 1):

You can use groovy split function -

```
def branchName = 'feature/XXX-111'
def newBranchName = branchName.split('/')[1]
println(newBranchName)
​
```

Output:

```
XXX-111
```

Comment: thank you but the branch name will be changing constantly, so that is why i am using the $GIT_BRANCH variable to pull in the branch name. So i dont think i can set branch_name = $GIT_BRANCH ?right?

Comment: You can set for sure